# Why does using flutter run not working in cmd

Tags: flutter, dart

I did not have a problem with the flutter yesterday, but it's just a few days when I `flutter run` that I'm running a project with `flutter run` This brings me to mind that in previous projects, has it

error is :

> C:\wamp64\www\whatsapp>flutter run Using hardware rendering with
>   device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts,
>   consider enabling software rendering with
>   "--enable-software-rendering". Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK
>   built for x86 in debug mode... Initializing gradle...
>   4.0s Resolving dependencies...                                          14.2s
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
>
> > Could not find aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971).   Searched in the
> >     following locations:
> >           https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Running
>   Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         8.3s
>   Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

Comment: Try 'flutter doctor' it sometimes fixes things.

Comment: flutter doctor in ok

Comment: Go to your local gradle folder and delete everything that is inside the "caches" directory. Then try to rebuild/run your project again.